# How to Get Recent 5 post in My Title bar?

Tags: plugins, posts

I Installed Recent Posts Plugin in my Wordpress site.It Shows Correct Answer but it Shows  "Recent Post" at Header position.I don't want that text. Unfortunately i  can't remove that.please help me ...Is there any other php coding Available?

Comment: Can you post some code?  At this point it would just be guesswork.

Comment: And let us know exactly which Recent Posts plugin you're using. There are a bunch. The only one called "Recent Posts" seems to only work up to WordPress 2.6.2.

Comment: am using Recent Posts(In Built with wp 3.1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah gotcha. Either you can use a different plugin that allows you to leave the title blank, or using the default Recent Posts widget type a single blank space in the Title area and click Save. That way the title will show as blank. Hope this helps!
Michelle